# My batch file is not working as fast as I want

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to process the data from a very large input file and to verify the values of 3 columns. It works for small files, but for the big ones it never stops. The first two lines from the file doesn't matter. I tried to echo something in the first for and even after 20 minutes the second value is not displayed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set inputFile=%1
set /a LineNumber=0
set ok=0
For /f " skip=1 tokens=6,7,8  delims= " %%b in (%inputfile%) do (
    set /a LineNumber+=1
    if "%%c"=="(" (
        set ok=0
        set /a FinalLineNumber=0
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=6,7,8  delims= " %%e in (%inputfile%) do (
            set /a FinalLineNumber+=1
            If "%%f"==")" (
                If "%%b"=="%%e" (
                    If "%%d"=="%%g" (
                        set ok=1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        if "!ok!"=="0" (
            echo %%b %%d
       )
    )
)
endlocal
```

And the input file is something like:

```
Name Adress No Nr Pers Cy   St   Y
a    122    43 54  2   23   (   56
g    345    45 32  5   23   +   56
f     54    34 10  4   23   )   56
g     34    76  2  5   24   (   56
```

The program should echo `Cy` and `Y` from the `g` line because the `St` `)` isn't in the file.
The file has cycles which start with "(" and end with ")". I have to find the cycles which aren't correctly used. A cycle is defined by `Cy` and `Y`. For more than one line to be in the same cycle the `Cy` and `Y` have to be the same.

Comment: I have formatted your code to add the indentation to it so that you can better see that you have two new lines where there shouldn't be any, _(lines `2` and `5`)_. Also you cannot use smart quotes, _(curly)_, you must use dumb quotes, _(straight)_. Your posted code therefore does not work for any files, small or big! If you were to provide some sample input file content, and show us exactly what you need to return, then we may be able to assist you better with your request. Please use the [edit] facility to update your question content with that information.

Comment: You have not changed all of the invalid double-quote characters, **`“`**, and **`”`**, to **`"`**.

Comment: the code is more bigger than what I wrote here.The problem is with the big files and how can i make it faster

Comment: Well the obvious thing would be not to read the entire content of the file twice. However, until you have provided some sample content, and the intended output from that, into formatted code boxes in your question, we will be unable to produce code solutions which do anything other than guess. This is a technical site, and in order to provide a technical answer, you need to suppy sufficient information for us to reproduce both the code and the environment. That is especially important when the speed of the execution is your main issue.

Comment: I cannot use just one for because after i find a ) I cannot go back to  find a previous (.A cycle can have another start cycle in it, or an end, or even both.

Comment: A `FOR /F` command always reads the entire file into memory before it proceeds with any commands that need to be executed by the `FOR` command.   Just reading a large file once will slow down your script.  Please do not post images of data or code.  Please delete your image and put the text of the input in your question by using the [edit] facility.

Comment: Essentially you are reading the file to the Nth Power + 1.  For every line in your file you are reading the file that many times plus 1.

Comment: And what can I do to process the data and not to read the file every time?

Comment: Even for your small demo data, your code doesn't echo your expected output. Btw. Your description of your expectation is a bit unclear. Why and how your code should output the line starting with `g`? And how many lines your real data-file contains, how many different `Cy` column values you expect?

Comment: Your code doesn't work, your explanations are unclear. How do you expect that someone can *improve* the performance?

Comment: It had some mistakes in it, sorry.I fixed them. I added some information too.

Comment: May the "cycles" be mixed? That is, all the lines of one cycle appear in sequence? Or two or more cycles can be mixed?

Comment: The cycles can be mixed

Comment: How many lines have the file? Approx... How many cycles? Approx

Comment: Aprox 3000-4000 lines and for cycles idk 1000

Comment: A 4000 lines is _not_ a "very large" file... **`;)`**  See my answer below:

Comment: There is an error, environment variable cycle[ not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a first attempt to solve your problem. Test it and report the result and desired modifications...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "inputFile=%~1"

for /F "skip=1 tokens=6,7,8" %%b in (%inputFile%) do (

   if "%%c" == "(" (

      rem Cycle begin
      if not defined cycle[%%b%%d] (
         set "cycle[%%b%%d]=("
      ) else (
         echo Cycle %%b %%d: start two times
      )

   ) else if "%%c" == ")" (

      rem Cycle ends
      if not defined cycle[%%b%%d] (
         echo Cycle %%b %%d: end with no start
      ) else (
         set "cycle[%%b%%d]="
      )

   )
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('set cycle[') do echo Cycle %%b: start with no end
```

Comment: In the last line change `('set cycle[')` by `('set cycle[ 2^>nul')` to eliminate the error message